# Why state of one of my components gets lost?

Tags: reactjs

Basically I am creating an input field component and it's rendered differently.
But when I press the refresh button, the values from inputs 1 and 3 remain but the value from input 2 gets reset every time.

index.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import MyInputField from "./MyInputField";

import "./styles.css";

const Method3 = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>Method 3</span>
      <MyInputField />
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const method1 = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>Method 1</span>
        <MyInputField />
      </div>
    );
  };

  const Method2 = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>Method 2</span>
        <MyInputField />
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{method1()}</div>
      <Method2 />
      <Method3 />

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setCounter(counter + 1);
        }}
      >
        Refresh me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

MyInputField

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const MyInputField = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  return (
    <input
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setValue(e.target.value);
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default MyInputField;
```

Working example here

https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-andras-06x72q

Thanks

When i console log the values I get empty after pressing refresh for the second input

Answer (score 0):

You should not define the `Method` inside the `App`, it will created on each render of `App`.

Move the `Method` outside, and instead of defining 3 times the same component, use `props` to give an id to each one:

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React; 

const Method = (props) => (
    <div>
        <span>Method {props.id}</span>
        <MyInputField id={props.id} />
    </div>
);

const MyInputField = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState("");
    return (
        <input value={value} onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)} />
    );
};

function App() {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Method id={1} />
            <Method id={2} />
            <Method id={3} />

            <button onClick={() => {
                console.log('Refresh')
                setCounter(counter + 1);
            }}> 
                Refresh me
            </button>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```